# conditionally excluding rows from being evaluated with dplyr::mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

I am populating a new column in a tibble by taking the log of the positive elements in another column, while not evaluating the negative values. I tried using if_else, ifelse and case_when to exclude the negative values from evaluation, but without success.

```
library(dplyr)
my_df <- tibble(n=c(-2,-1,0,1,2,3))
my_df %>% mutate(log_n = if_else(n > 0, log(n), NA_real_))
```

or

```
my_df %>% mutate(log_n = case_when(n > 0 ~ log(n),
                                  TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

work as expected but throw warnings about `NaNs` being generated by the `log` function:

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com) this behaviour could be avoided using a dummy column:

```
my_df  %>% 
group_by(xx= n <= 0) %>% 
mutate(test = ifelse(xx, NA_real_, log(n))) %>%
ungroup %>% 
select(-xx)
```

Are there any less cumbersome methods to only evaluate the positive values?

Comment: You want to avoid warnings?

Comment: yes I do, and I have edited the text to clarify this

Comment: use `if_else(n > 0, log(n), NA_real_)` You cannot have `log(0)` so you need to do `>` rather than `>=`

Comment: log(0) generates -Inf; that is not a problem in my case. Still edited the code to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that the `if_else` does not cover this, You can do a math trick:

```
my_df %>% 
   mutate(log_n = NA^(n < 0) * log(abs(n)))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
      n    log_n
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1    -2   NA    
2    -1   NA    
3     0 -Inf    
4     1    0    
5     2    0.693
6     3    1.10
```

Or you could do:

```
my_df %>% 
   mutate(log_n = log(`is.na<-`(n, n < 0)))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
      n    log_n
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1    -2   NA    
2    -1   NA    
3     0 -Inf    
4     1    0    
5     2    0.693
6     3    1.10
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is very creative and perfect for this situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The warning is correctly generated by `log` because `if_else` evaluates the entire expression for the `true` and `false` arguments (type `if_else` into console without brackets to see, or look on [Github](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/if_else.R)). In other words, the function does not calculate `log(x)` only for those values where the condition is true; it calculates it for all values and then only returns ones where the condition is true. So you get the warnings when log is calculated on all the negative values. It has nothing to do with `mutate` specifically which just surfaces warnings from functions it calls; you can see this by trying to call log on a simple vector rather than a dataframe column.

I think to avoid this (without `suppressWarnings` or exception handling) you need to drop negative values before calculating `log`. You could either do this inline, or with a small helper function.

```r
library(dplyr)

my_df <- tibble(n = c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3))

log_quiet <- function(x, base = exp(1)) {
  x[x < 0] <- NA
  log(x, base)
}

my_df %>%
  mutate(
    log_n = n %>% `[<-`(. < 0, NA) %>% log(),
    log_quiet = log_quiet(n)
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>       n    log_n log_quiet
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1    -2   NA        NA    
#> 2    -1   NA        NA    
#> 3     0 -Inf      -Inf    
#> 4     1    0         0    
#> 5     2    0.693     0.693
#> 6     3    1.10      1.10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Surely I will use either suggested solution in the future